# why was the Lord Regent killed?

Tags: dishonored

So when I was playing dishonored, I'm on a non-lethal path btw which i did, the Lord regent died when I knocked him out while his confession was playing. is this a bug or something really suppose to happened. I've read in the wiki that when you've played his confession, the guards will take him into custody, while he try to escape, he will be killed. is this what happened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you knocked him out and saw him die after with no guards around, that sounds like a bug. Perhaps the guard thought the Lord Regentbeing unconscious was the same as him fleeing, in which case they would've killed him.

The non-lethal takedown for the Lord Regent involves playing the confession, after which one of the following happens:

- The Lord Regent is killed by guards in a non-scripted way if he flees after the confession plays. This can happen if you possess him, or if you attack him or the guards while he's being led out of the tower.
- The Lord Regent is arrested, led out of the tower, and then tries to flee and is killed by guards in a scripted way if you're on a high-chaos playthrough.
- The Lord Regent is arrested, led out of the tower, and survives to be thrown in Coldridge Prison if you're on a low-chaos playthrough.

Source: http://dishonored.wikia.com/wiki/Return_to_the_Tower

Answer (score 1):

It is possible for the regent to try to escape if you interfere with his arrest. In this case the guards attack and may kill him. Knocking him out must have triggered that when it became impossible to arrest the unconscious regent.

If you knock someone out and they later die, it is counted as a kill- usually because it's your fault.